# How do I make the creation of an anonymous user conditional for IIS6, but not IIS7 in WIX?

Tags: iis-7, wix, installation, iis-6, wix3.5

I'm upgrading an old WiX installer that was made for IIS6 to work in IIS7.  We create an anonymous user and assign that user to the WorkerProcessGroup, however, in IIS7 that isn't necessary and the installer has trouble adding user to group since IIS_WPG doesn't exist.

I can make the creation of the user conditional by placing:

```
<Condition><![CDATA[(INETSTPMAJORVERSION = "#6")]]></Condition>
```

right above the user component, but there's another part that creates the virtual directory that then fails:

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir ...
    <iis:WebDirProperties ...
        AnonymousUser="IusrThatIWasSupposedToMakeButDidntBecauseItsIIS7"
```

WiX won't take the "Condition" above the "iis:WebDirProperties" but will above the "iis:WebVirtualDir".  Thing is, there are a LOT of settings (280 lines) in that tag and I don't want to copy/paste the whole thing to have the seperate condition.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to add the `Condition` element under the `Component` elements. Sorry, there isn't a way to apply the same condition to many components today.